# in x64 Windows is there a way to run a Runtime.exec() process avoiding 'Registry redirection'

Tags: java, registry, wow64, runtime.exec

Our app runs in jvm 32 bit, even when in windows x64. Now, at some point, I need to access some registry values, for example HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/mycomp.

I do this by executing

```
cmd /C reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\mycop
```

from Runtime.exec() and parsing the output. This works fine when running on windows 32b, the problem is when on x64, I cannot find the key, as the shell I run is a 32 bit process, and due to [Registry Redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384232(VS.85).aspx) I would get the key if it was on  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/wow6432Node/mycop

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anybody tries this...I was not able to do this and had to resort to another approach that my scenario supported.